# Enhanced text box (Multi line Rich Text Box in SharePoint 2013) wont work with font color and images? Any Solution for it?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

when I try to copy paste an image from Word file to the enhanced text box(Multi line Rich Text Box in SharePoint 2013) it wont work because the enhanced text box at the back end uses nothing but formatted html, if you check the html source of it. Now when you copy a graphic from one one item to another it gets pasted because it still has a reference to add to the src of the image tag, but when you paste from the clipboard there is no reference to be added to the img html tag for the enhanced text box, I can paste rich text just fine (Documents in word copy font sizes correctly) but font color and images are left out. Even I've tried copying the image in a number of different ways (copy file direct from File Explorer, copy image form word) and no luck. Do anybody have the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion copying from Word into a Richtextbox is not a good idea. Cause it is very hard to modify the content later through the Richtextbox, cause it is not standard html. I dont think that there is a solution for this. Maybe you can try a industry standard solution like Telerik RAD Editor for SharePoint or try to implement CKEditor or TinyMCE by yourself?

Comment: I have used KWizCom paste+ that is deployed on the ribbon of my SharePoint List but still disabled like the normal paste option besides it, when copying the content from the word file to my Multiline Enhanced  Rich text box. Please provide some solution with respect to SharePoint on Premises for it. Any wsp or something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copy and paste the image, try to upload the image to a SharePoint library and then reference it with HTML in your text box.

**EDIT:**

Another thing you can do is encode the image to base64 and paste the code in a img element:  https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: Don't want to upload the images this way... just want to copy whole of the text and images from a word file and paste that to the Multi line Rich Text Box column in SharePoint On Premises

Comment: I think it's not possible to do copy-paste from Word to SharePoint. See my new edit, I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks Celtik,  but this is not what I'm searching for. And rather it doesn't allow me even to copy the image or css from clipboard.